# cmake disabling MSVC incremental linking

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

**Background**

I have some project which after a while (many builds when developing) consumes so many computer resources during linking process. So much that my machine becomes unresponsive (even mouse do not move).

My project has many static libraries (4) targets and many executable (2 are production excusable and 4 for testing purposes).

Quick googling indicated that problem is incremental linking. I've [found this](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-disable-incremental-linking-for-visual-studio-2022/4817) as solution for cmake. And applied fix from answer:

```
cmake -A x64 -Thost=x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" .. ^
    -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG="/DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO" ^
    -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE="/DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO" ^
    -DCMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG="/DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO" ^
    -DCMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE="/DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO" ^
    -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG="/DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO" ^
    -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE="/DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO" ^
    -DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG="/DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO" ^
    -DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE="/DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO"
```

**Problem**

So far my machine do not show any signs of hangs, but in build logs I see this:

```
  Generating Code...
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/DEBUG'; ignored [F:\repos\Src\build64\Project\Project.vcxproj]
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/INCREMENTAL:NO'; ignored [F:\repos\Src\build64\Project\Project.vcxproj]
```

Based on [MSVC linker documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/incremental-link-incrementally?view=msvc-160) this should be fine!

**Question**

How it is possible I have this logs? Did I disabled incremental linking or not (just data do not grow enough to cause a problem)? If I didn't how I can fix this problem?

Comment: That's odd. Incremental linking should *reduce* resource use and speed up builds. My crystal ball says "the real problem is probably something else".

Comment: Adding the `/DEBUG` flag to a release build is strange (and won't help your build times)

Comment: @JesperJuhl you can find in google that many people are complaining about performance of incremental linking. Once after a longer time I deleted build results then build project again with same settings and just by doing that I regained 30GB of disc space. Most of this space was occupied by `*.pdb` files.

Comment: I also disable it for RELEASE builds. My linker settings in MSVC branch use the `add_link_options` command `add_link_options(
   /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
   /DEBUG
   $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/INCREMENTAL:NO> # Disable incremental linking.
   $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/OPT:REF> # Remove unreferenced functions and data.
   $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/OPT:ICF> # Identical COMDAT folding.
   $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/INCREMENTAL> # Do incremental linking.
   $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/OPT:NOREF> # No unreferenced data elimination.
   $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/OPT:NOICF> # No Identical COMDAT folding.
  )`

Comment: @vre Note I do not want to modify `CMakeLists.txt` just pass arguments for configuration phase, but will try tweak your version of flags.

Comment: What type is your target when this linker warnings are shown? AFAIK, for MSVC you do not need to add those settings for a static library creation.

Comment: @vre that is interesting, I have lots of static libraries and then just couple exectutables, so you comment I think is way to solve problem with this log entry. Thanks. You can turn it to an answer (will approve it after verification). I will simply remove `-DCMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_*`

Comment: I just inspected logs, yet this log shows only for static libraries.

Comment: Here I was thinking cmake was disabling incremental linking. I would suggest reworking the headline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the static linker flags you do not need to add those options. In case of MSVC `lib.exe` is used as *static linker* and that one does not understand these options.

For most projects of mine I use inside the CMakeLists.txt the `add_link_options` command to let CMake properly add the link options to the linker commands.

```
add_link_options(
    /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
    /DEBUG
    $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/INCREMENTAL:NO> # Disable incremental linking.
    $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/OPT:REF> # Remove unreferenced functions and data.
    $<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/OPT:ICF> # Identical COMDAT folding.
    $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/INCREMENTAL> # Do incremental linking.
    $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/OPT:NOREF> # No unreferenced data elimination.
    $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/OPT:NOICF> # No Identical COMDAT folding.
)
```

Comment: I rarely build release on my machine, incremental linking is problematic in debug mode. To reproduce issue you need change code and build multiple times to make  `*.pdb` large enough to show problem.